# checkbox can not see from the interface flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UJae.png)[This is how my page works. I want to get checkbox ticked and get the post paid number then can click the continue button. In my code checkbox is in between text and text form field Why i can not see my check box here and this is my code.]

```
 new Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                child: new Form(
                  child: new Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        "Are you a post paid customer",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          fontSize: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Checkbox(
                          activeColor: Colors.blue,
                          value: _isChecked,
                          onChanged: (bool val){
                            onChanged(val);}
                      ),
                      new TextFormField(
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Post Paid Number",
                        ),
                        obscureText: true,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      ),
                      new Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                      ),
                      new MaterialButton(
                        height: 50.0,
                        minWidth: 150.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        splashColor: Colors.blue,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: new Text("Continue"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new RegPage()),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated your code and got it working.

You need to change `_isChecked` in Checkbox's onChanged like:

```
onChanged: (val) {
  setState(() {
    _isChecked = !_isChecked;
  });
}),
```

Make sure to do it in `setState` or the change wont be reflected on UI.

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_demo/sample_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyHomePageState createState() {
    return new MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _isChecked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('SO HELP'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
        child: new Form(
          child: new Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(
                  "Are you a post paid customer",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
                new Checkbox(
                    activeColor: Colors.blue,
                    value: _isChecked,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isChecked = !_isChecked;
                      });
                    }),
                new TextFormField(
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Post Paid Number",
                  ),
                  obscureText: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                ),
                new Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                ),
                new MaterialButton(
                  height: 50.0,
                  minWidth: 150.0,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  splashColor: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  child: new Text("Continue"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new RegPage());
                  },
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i got it and i have to try it this way also BTW do you know how to change a border color of a checkbox.

Comment: If you find this answer correct please mark it as correct. I will soon reply with checkbox border color

Comment: You can do that by changing property `unselectedWidgetColor` in `ThemeData`.